# Can not read property of $promise then undefined?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am calling factory from controller trying to resolve $promise if its thenable get response.data , but i am getting an error "can not read property of 'then' undefined". I am new to AngularJS please let me know where i have coded wrong.

mfactory.js

```
 getAlldocs : function (assessmentId){
                        $http.get('app/upload/getallDoc/' +assessmentId);
                      }
```

main.js

```
  $scope.riskAssessmentDTO.riskAssessmentKey = id;
        rcsaAssessmentService.getAlldocs(id,function(response){
          assessmentData = response.data;
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the `$http` call from your function:

```
getAlldocs : function (assessmentId){
  return $http.get('app/upload/getallDoc/' +assessmentId);
}
```

Or you won't return a promise at all.

Comment: @aftab No you only voted up, click the checkmark icon also :)

Comment: Sorry i thought i did it